# How to find PSNR from two images with different size in python

Tags: python, arrays, image, image-processing

I have 2 images, one original and other is reconstructed from the original via some processing. I want to find the PSNR for the reconstructed image The original has a size of `(180, 180)` but the reconstructed image has size of `(71,81)`. I am using cv2.reshape() to reshape the reconstructed image.

```
shape = 180
reconstructed = cv2.resize(reconstructed, (shape,shape))
reconstructed = cv2.normalize(reconstructed, None, alpha=0, beta = 255, norm_type= cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
original = cv2.normalize(original, None, alpha=0, beta = 255, norm_type= cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
MSE = np.mean((original - reconstructed)**2)
PSNR = 10*np.log10(255**2/MSE)
print(PSNR)
```

Since the sizes do not match and I have to calculate PSNR, I'm afraid that there might be some alignment issues and thus it may give wrong PSNR. What can be done to do calculate the PSNR accurately?

Comment: You should resize it with cv2.resize() and check the result. You can worry about alignment issues after you've tried that. If that causes a problem you can post that as a more specific question along with the pictures and code you used.

Comment: would be great if you could provide the data for us, so we could reverse engineer.

Comment: oh a bounty attracted someone to answer - if that is not the very idea of a bounty..

Comment: I wouldn't recommend answering an unclear question. this site itself does not recommend doing that (*because* such answers tap in the dark and miss, AND because the original question is unsuitable to be in a Q&A database that is Stack Overflow). instead you should request clarification. "the data" might help make educated guesses as to the nature of this reconstruction. I would rather see details on the reconstruction than just the data.

Comment: yeah I would say data can speak loudly in such a case. That is why i asked for it. Whether this is not fit for a database that is SO, will be decided whether enough vote to close this question. And until then I opt for answering questions, at least that is my understanding of the community that is SO. I love how you care for this platform, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Scaffolding**

First, it would be great if you could provide the data next time. Or at least some means to generate something that you feel is close enough to your data, so that the answers are actually useful to you.

Because we have been missing that, I build some little scaffolding to generate an original, and a reconstructed image where one can set the noise level.

**Resize instead of reshape**

That being out of the way. You want to resize. Since the sizes are different and reshape requires that the total number of elements in the array remains the same. If you reshape an array without keeping the total number of elements constant, it would result in a distorted representation or an error (probably why you get an error when reshaping). Resizing using `cv2.resize` is more suitable for this scenario as it interpolates the pixel values to fit the new dimensions, ensuring that the resized image is a meaningful representation of the original image in a different size.

**Dealing with Alignment issues**

Now that you actually get a PSNR value, you can start thinking about how you want that interpolation of your reconstructed image to happen during resize. This depends on your data and the resize method gives you 5 options to choose from - read the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize). If you don't know which to choose, run an experiment to find out.

**My code for anyone who wants to play or build on top of it for another answer.**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def generate_dummy_image(size):
    return np.random.randint(0, 1, size, dtype=np.uint8)

def add_noise(image, noise_level):
    noise = np.random.normal(0, noise_level, image.shape).astype(np.uint8)
    noisy_image = cv2.add(image, noise)
    return noisy_image

# Generate original image (180, 180)
original_image_size = (180, 180)
original = generate_dummy_image(original_image_size)

# Generate reconstructed image (71, 81) with added noise
reconstructed_image_size = (71, 81)
reconstructed = generate_dummy_image(reconstructed_image_size)
noise_level = 20  # You can adjust the noise level as needed
reconstructed = add_noise(reconstructed, noise_level)

resized_reconstructed_image = cv2.resize(reconstructed, (original.shape[1], original.shape[0]))

# Calculate PSNR
psnr = cv2.PSNR(original, resized_reconstructed_image)
print(f"PSNR: {psnr} dB")


# Display images (optional)
# cv2.imshow('Original Image', original)
# cv2.imshow('Reconstructed Image with Noise', reconstructed)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
# cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I am dealing with alignment, which in my opinion is a question of approximation in that case. Alignment or the choice of approximation can only be adressed seriously when knowing the data (which I am waiting for at this point). So I stand by my word and proposal: "This depends on your data and the resize method gives you 5 options to choose from - read the docs. If you don't know which to choose, run an experiment to find out." - I do not see where your comment adds any value by the way, other than badmouthing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work correctly even if your reconstructed image size don’t match with original image . Because you are resizing them in the second line of code and you are also normalizing both images to make sure they are of same data type and value range before calculation of psnr .

If you still find error in psnr value recheck the code for image paths and also try this

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

 

def calculate_psnr(original, reconstructed):

 

    original = cv2.resize(original, reconstructed.shape[:2])

 

  original = original.astype("float32") / 255.0

 

  reconstructed = reconstructed.astype("float32") / 255.0

 

  mse = np.mean((original - reconstructed)**2)

 

  psnr = 10 * np.log10(255**2 / mse)

 

  return psnr

 

original = cv2.imread("original_image.png")

 

reconstructed = cv2.imread("reconstructed_image.png")

 

psnr = calculate_psnr(original, reconstructed)

 

print(f"PSNR: {psnr:.2f}")
```